# Generate an image similar to image name

Tags: node.js, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, pre-trained-model, jimp

I have a requirement where I want to generate an image that is similar to my item name. For eg. if my item name is Butter Chicken then I want an image to be generated of butter chicken. My requirement is only food specific. I looked into DeepAI image API but it generating low-quality images. Can anyone suggest how can I do this?
PS: I want to do this in NodeJs.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you to use API service from Dalle-2, Midjourney, Adobe Firefly etc,  you must have cache mechanism and token similarity identification system at your end to avoid duplicate API calls for similar phrases like Butter Chicken and ButterChicken,

1. https://docs.midjourney.com/
2. https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference
3. https://www.adobe.com/sensei/generative-ai/firefly.html

If your stack is server less,then better integrate with a mid layer CDN